# Can a possessive S be attached to nouns that are not human beings (or animals)?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Can a *possessive S* be attached to nouns that are not human beings (or animals)?

For example, instead of saying "**the back of the chair**", can I say "**the chair's back**"?

I remember learning that not everything can get a possessive s, but this issue is not clear to me.

Comment: [The possessive 's can be applied to anything, not just living things.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/possessives.htm)  Some people think it's bad form to use it with inanimate objects, but it's not a rule; you can use it with anything and be grammatically correct.

Comment: Thank you. so then can I use it also for plural forms - such as: "people's money" (instead of "money of the people")?

Comment: Yes, it can be used with plural forms too, although if the word ends with *s* we just add an apostrophe instead of apostrophe s: people's money, boys' clothes, cats' feet, oxen's horns, etc.

Comment: The possessive can be used with any noun, but for many nouns it's more common to use "of" when describing composition (e.g. the back of the chair)

Answer (score 2):

You can use it with any noun phrase, animate or not; but there is a tendency to use it with things that have volition (people, animals, organisations).

So if I search for "chair's" in the [NOW corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/now/), there are 613 hits; but (on my count) 94 out of the first 100 are using "chair" in its sense of "chairman/chairwoman of a meeting or organisation", and only six mean an inanimate object.

Similarly, "street's" gets 6262 hits, but almost every one is following a name (a third of those are "Wall Street's", and another 800 are "Coronation Street's", "Sesame Street's" or "Downing Street's" - all of these are or can be quasi-persons.)

Having said that, "car's" and "kitchen's" (for example) certainly do get some hits.