# Genitive s for objects

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

If you say the aim of Ben, you can also say **Ben's** aim.

If you say the objective of the project (which is not a person but an object), do you say the **project's** objective or the **projects** objective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> project's objective

The objective "belongs" to the project, so you would use 's to indicate ownership. You can say "the project's name" or "the project's staff".

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly use the apostrophe-s possessive about a project, but it would be unusual. We don't tend to use this this form when a thing is the possessor (see this [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109338/can-a-possessive-s-be-attached-to-nouns-that-are-not-human-beings-or-animals)).

You could stick to the of-possessive form, but for **project** we can also make a compound noun, for example **project objective**, **project name** and **project team**.

There is a lot of variation in which form is preferred: see these NGrams for [project objective](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=project%27s%20objective%2C%20project%20objective%2Cobjective%20of%20the%20project&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cproject%20%27s%20objective%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproject%20objective%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobjective%20of%20the%20project%3B%2Cc0), [project name](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=project%27s%20name%2Cproject%20name%2Cname%20of%20the%20project&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cproject%20%27s%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproject%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cname%20of%20the%20project%3B%2Cc0), [project staff](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=project%27s%20staff%2Cproject%20staff%2Cstaff%20of%20the%20project&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cproject%20%27s%20staff%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproject%20staff%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstaff%20of%20the%20project%3B%2Cc0) and [project team](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=project%27s%20team%2Cproject%20team%2Cteam%20of%20the%20project&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cproject%20%27s%20team%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproject%20team%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cteam%20of%20the%20project%3B%2Cc0)

Similarly, with [hill](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20hill%27s%20top%2C%20the%20hilltop%2C%20the%20hill%20top%2C%20the%20top%20of%20the%20hill&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20hill%20%27s%20top%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20hilltop%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20hill%20top%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20top%20of%20the%20hill%3B%2Cc0), you can say **the top of the hill** or **the hilltop**, but hardly ever **the hill's top**;